# Error installing @ngrx/store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm having problems installing @ngrx/store

my set up:

node 8.9.3,
npm 5.5.1,
angular cli 1.7.4,
angular 5.2.0

I'm using angular cli to create an angular app then installing @ngrx/store with

```
npm install @ngrx/store --save
```

This gives me the error

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/chris.wright/node_modules/@ngrx/store'
```

If I run with sudo

```
sudo npm install @ngrx/store --save
```

I dont get an error but the @ngrx doesnt appear in the node_modules folder or in the package.json

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this or how I might install @ngrx/store

Comment: Silly, but are you sure you are running this from the package directory?

Comment: Yes, I'm have run it from the package directory

Comment: Other packages installing ok? Try inspecting the logs after running this: `npm i @ngrx/store --loglevel verbose`. Also you don't need `--save` on > npm version 4.

Comment: What is your operating system? I get this error sometimes with VSCode and Windows 7/10. Simply relaunching vscode helps. Don't know why this happens.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you manually add these lines in the `package.json` and then `npm install`?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ngrx/effects": "^5.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^5.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^5.2.0",
```

Given the information you have provided so far, this is my best advice. Sounds like a system related/node permission, so more information to Qs such as 'Do multiple users have write access to the current directory?' would be needed for more hints.